# Particular resolution in media queries

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to change the CSS of a div in a particular resolution.

For example:

```
@media only (width: 320px){do something}
```

I tried with that code but didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something...

```
@media only screen and (width: 320px) {do something}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I had never had to use media queries for a particular resolution.